# How to implement java MessageDigest with CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, java, cryptojs

JAVA CODE:

```java
byte[] n;
byte[] m;
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
digest.reset();
digest.update(n);
byte[] hashed = digest.digest(m);
StringBuilder hexValue = new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : hashed) {
    int val = ((int) b) & 0xff;
    if (val < 16) {
       hexValue.append("0");
    }
    hexValue.append(Integer.toHexString(val));
 }
System.out.println(hexValue.toString());
```

How to implement the above code with CryptoJS ?
Thanks!

Comment: SO is not a code porting service. Post your recent CryptoJS code and describe your problem. Perhaps a look at the [CryptoJS documentation for hashing](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-hashing-output) would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The following code：

```js
var n; // n="abc"
var m; // m="123"
var sha1 = CryptoJS.algo.SHA1.create();
sha1.update(n);
var hashed = sha1.finalize(m);
console.log(hashed.toString());
```